# How to determine if a pixel in a GIF is transparent (.NET)

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, gif

How can I determine if a particular pixel in a GIF image is transparent in C#? I can see the MakeTransparent method in Bitmap, but nothing to determine if it is actually transparent already.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GetPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx) and then look at the [Alpha component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.a.aspx) of the `Color` instance returned. 0 = fully transparent.

If you need to loop through all (or many) pixels, be aware that GetPixel is quite slow. A faster, but more involved way, is to use LockBits to lock the data in memory, then look at the bitmap data directly.